# SVGs are inconsistent in their color behavior, when a background color is overlaid upon them. (Browser)

Tags: css, svg, web, inkscape

I'm working on some background art, and I'm going to be using it alongside a background color which will be overlaid on it. But the behavior of the background color overlay doesn't make sense. The color of the lines are different than the color of the squares when a background color is applied, but the same when there is no background

```
body {
    background-color: #2d3137; /*Background 1*/
    background-image: url('/static/bg.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Original:
[image: The original svg with no background.]

Background #1:
[image: The same svg rendered with a background]

Background #2:
[image: The same svg rendered with another background]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's not a colour difference, it's just the effect of antialiasing.

Answer (score 0):

The colors are EXACTLY THE SAME. Doublechecked with color picker tool.

Comment: The SVG "is this dress gold or blue" picture